# Phase shifting via sin addition

Tags: trigonometry

Is it possible to shift a reference sin wave of unit amplitude with the addition of another sin wave of unit amplitude beyond ±π/2?

Stated a different way, is Φ limited to <±π/2 in the following equation: sin(x)+sin(x-Θ)=c*sin(Φ)?

Is the result [c*sin(Φ)]/|c|=-sin(x) not achievable with addition of unit amplitude sin waves?

It seems like there is a disconnect at Θ=π similar to a tangent function at π/2.

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you are asking.  Your equation $\sin(x)+\sin(x-\Theta)$ is not equal to $\sin(\phi)$ for many $x$ and $\theta$, since $\sin(x)+\sin(x-\Theta)$ can be outside the range $-1 \le y \le 1$.  For instance, $\sin(0.2)+\sin(1.2)=1.13...$ so this is not equal to $\sin  \phi$ for any $\phi$.

Comment: I never specified the result was of unit amplitude. I added a constant to the equation. I guess I am thinking more along the lines of sin as a function of x. As seen in the plots here: http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%28x%29%2C+sin%28x%29%2Bsin%28x%2B1%29&x=0&y=0

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}\sin x + \sin(x - \Theta) &= \sin x + \sin x\cos \Theta - \cos x \sin \Theta
\\ &= (1+\cos\Theta)\sin x - \sin\Theta\cos x
\\&=a \sin x + b\cos x
\\&=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\left(\frac a{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\sin x + \frac b{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\cos x\right)
\\&=c\left(\cos\phi\sin x + \sin\phi\cos x\right)
\\&= c\sin(x + \phi)\end{align}$$

In general, the sum of two sinusoids of the same period is another sinusoid of that period.

**Edit:**

Note that in the derivation
$$1+\cos \Theta = c\cos\phi \qquad \sin \Theta = -c \sin \phi$$
so if you start with $\phi$, and solve $\cos \Theta = c\cos\phi - 1$, it follows that $$1 = \cos^2\Theta + \sin^2 \Theta = c^2 + 1 - 2c\cos\phi$$
So, $c = 2\cos \phi$, which we can plug back into the sine equation to get

$$\sin \Theta = -2\cos\phi\sin\phi = \sin(-2\phi)$$
So $\Theta = k\pi - (-1)^k2\phi$ for any integer value of $k$ can result in the offset of $\phi$, regardless of the $\phi$ chosen.

Comment: It's seems like you are describing the same property of sin addition I described in my question. This doesn't answer the question of: is there an input Θ that can produce an output phase of Φ=±π?

Comment: In the version of the question that I answered (nearly a day before you edited it to include the "<"), you appeared to think the addition worked only when $\phi =\pm \pi/2$, so I went though the derivation to show you that it works in general. I'm sorry, but I can only respond to the question you asked, not the question you had intended.

Comment: I have added a calculation in reverse to show that you can obtain any phase shift.

Comment: Sorry for the edit, I mistakenly left the "<" out when I originally posted the question. Thank you for still responding.
The equation Θ=kπ−(−1)<sup>k</sup>2ϕ; k=int seems to break down for ϕ>π/2.
For example if I evaluate at k=1, ϕ=3π/4, I obtain Θ=5π/2. However, sin(x)+sin(x+5π/2)=√2sin(x+π/4).
if I evaluate at k=1, ϕ=π, I obtain Θ=3π. However, sin(x)+sin(x+3π)=2sin(x).